# Exclude model from Railroady digram

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, erd

I am trying to create an ER diagram for my project using `RailRoady`. I am also using `PaperTrail` gem. because of this my ERD is all messed up. Is there any way to exclude PaperTrail::version table from ERD?

I went through following issue but couldn't understand much

https://github.com/preston/railroady/issues/54

and

https://github.com/preston/railroady/pull/115

Can anyone give a snippet / Example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Stumbled across your question today and followed to that first linked issue to [this comment](https://github.com/preston/railroady/issues/54#issuecomment-87469325). I'm not entirely sure how you're using RailRoady, but what worked for me looked like this:

```
$ railroady -M -s $picked | sed '/PaperTrail/d' > picked.dot
```

Here, `-M` signifies models specifically and `-s $picked` passes my own list of model files where `$picked` looks like this:

```
./app/models/my_model.rb,./app/models/another_model.rb,./app/models/a_third_model.rb
```

I don't think it's necessary to specify files; it's just what I was doing because I only wanted to map certain files. I then pipe it to `sed`, which removes lines that mention PaperTrail, before outputting it to `picked.dot`.

Like I said, I don't know your specific use case, but this worked for me.